# Does immutable label vs val have any effect on the return type of a method?

Tags: scala, immutability

The title explains the question, and here is a code sample:

```
def foo(): String = {
    var result: String = new String()
    result
}

def bar(): String = {
    val result = new String()
    result
}
```

Do var vs. val only have an effect on the variable in the scope of the method? Or does the return type implicitly maintain the immutability/mutability status? E.g. is the return type from bar() still immutable?

Forgive my ignorance, I am completely new to scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of both methods is String. Whether the value returned was from a val or var is irrelevant, they both return a String.  The val or var is in local scope, it’s not something being closed over, and it ceases to exist once the method call concludes. one of Scala’s goals is to have strong typing, so you can chain functions together and have some confidence that if it compiles it might actually work; if a method’s internal implementation played into how you had to treat its return value this would all fall apart.

Whether an object itself is mutable depends on how the object is implemented, not on how it is referenced. A String is immutable because its designers made sure there was no way to modify its internal state. var only means the variable allows the reference to be swapped out for another one.

Java language discussions about immutability or what a reference is are applicable to Scala too.

Comment: This is more eloquent than mine. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In short, `var` and `val` mark the ability and inability, respectively, to reassign to a name within a given scope.

`val` means the reference to the object in this scope cannot change; the underlying *object* may change, though. `var` means the object being referenced in this scope can change, so it can be reassigned.

Basically, if the object that's leaving the scope of the function is a mutable one, it can be mutated irrespective of `var` or `val`.

See the following example:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

scala> def foo(): ArrayBuffer[Int] = {
     |   val buff = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
     |   buff
     | }
foo: ()scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]

scala> def bar(): ArrayBuffer[Int] = {
     |   var buff = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
     |   buff
     | }
bar: ()scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]

scala> val fooBuff = foo()
fooBuff: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()

scala> fooBuff.append(1)

scala> val barBuff = bar()
barBuff: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()

scala> barBuff.append(1)

scala> println(fooBuff); println(barBuff)
ArrayBuffer(1)
ArrayBuffer(1)
```

However, if the underlying object is not a mutable one, it won't be mutable outside the scope.

For more information, see [this post](https://www.daveoncode.com/2018/01/15/understanding-mutability-and-immutability-in-scala/).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that `val` and `var` have no influence on the return type. They only affect assignment to that label within the scope of the method. So, for my simplified example code above, they are functionally identical, right? (When I say "functional identical" I am talking about execution. I am not interested in any underlying differences in how they are compiled, or the resulting bytecode. Just the behavior)

Comment: That's correct. And to be clear, `String` is an immutable _object_, so it will never be mutable -- simply replaceable.

Comment: Oh, and as an aside: this is actually a nice guarantee and how many library developers make their code efficient: by limiting the scope of mutability to a function and returning the immutable version to the caller.

Comment: That is funny, because that is exactly my scenario. I am seeking reassurance that I haven't broken the contract for a library function that I am optimizing.